# Understanding && in PHP if -clause

Tags: php, if-statement

**How can you get `1` as an output from #2?**

## #1

I ran this code

```
echo validate_email ( $email );
echo validate_password ( $password );
echo validate_username ( $username );
```

I get

```
111
```

which means that everything is ok.

## #2

I run this code

```
function validate ( $email, $password, $username ) {
    if (  (validate_email ( $email ) == 1)
        AND (validate_password ( $password ) == 1)
        AND (validate_username ( $username ) == 1 ) )
            return 1;
}
echo validate ($email, $password, $username );
```

I get nothing as an ouput.

I tried to fix the problem by changing `AND` to `&&` but the same output remains.
The output should be `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get nothing as output because you are only *returning* `1`, not actually echo-ing it. Things don't get echo-ed to the user unless you tell PHP to do so.

Example:

```
function test() {
    if (  (validate_email ( $email ) == 1)
        AND (validate_password ( $password ) == 1)
        AND (validate_username ( $username ) == 1 ) )
            return 1;
    else
            return 0;

echo test();
```

Also, here are a couple of points on `if` in general:

- You should probably use `&&` instead of `AND` as the former is more common.
- You don't need the `== 1` bit in there - `1` is always `TRUE`. Example:

  ```
  if ( validate_email($email) ) // correct email
  ```

  Instead of:

  ```
  if ( validate_email($email) == 1 ) // correct email
  ```

Comment: The missing `echo` was a bug in my question. I fixed it. I removed these `== 1` in my code, and the code started to work as expectde. -- This suggests me that two last lines of code are not equivalent. This is strange, since the two lines should be equivalent.

Comment: @Masi: your validate_*() functions are probably returning true instead of 1, thats why strict comparison (=== instead of ==) didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you **echo** the output of each function.
In the second example you **return** 1 if they all equal 1.

Returning something doesn't output it to STDOUT. You need to echo it if you want that.